# How does await cast mongoose query to promise?

Tags: mongoose, async-await

I missed exec() function call on mongoose query and then node app got a high CPU utilization. In chrome profiler i saw 35% of total usage in mongoose deserialize function calls. Can anybody explain that is going when await casts this model to Promise?

```
//Many deserialize calls and high CPU usage
let messages = await Models.Message.find({});    

//All fine!
messages = await Models.Message.find({}).exec();
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose Query model is **thenable**. In my case

1. **await** cast Object with **Promise.resolve()**,
2. Then **Promise.resolve** call **then()** function of Object
3. **then()** function returns Promise

I see it is so expensive to cast the object to Promise.

> /**  * Executes the query returning a `Promise` which will be  *
>   resolved with either the doc(s) or rejected with the error.  *  *
>   @param {Function} [resolve]  * @param {Function} [reject]  * @return
>   {Promise}  * @api public  */

```
Query.prototype.then = function(resolve, reject) {
  return this.exec().then(resolve, reject);
};
```